# C++ Flickering When Clearing the Console

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a loading animation for a program I'm making with the C++ console, I have been using system("cls") to clear the console (I know it is bad practice), but the main problem is that the screen flickers when I run the program. My code looks something like this:

Are there a way to fix the flickering? Thanks.

```
//loop
system("cls");
cout << "Loading..." << num << "%";
```

Comment: I would suggest using a library that has solved these problems already, e.g. PDcurses, or [Windows API console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)

Comment: You should try this one: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/99261/how-to-performing-clear-screen-cls-in-a-console-application

Answer (score 2):

While you can do as a commenter suggested and use a curses style library, you're probably looking for `SetConsoleCursorPosition` (2017 docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition)

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleCursorPosition(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_ COORD  dwCursorPosition
);
```

**Parameters**

> hConsoleOutput [in]
>
> A handle to the console screen buffer. The handle must have the GENERIC_READ access right. For more information, see Console Buffer Security and Access Rights.
>
> dwCursorPosition [in]
>
> A COORD structure that specifies the new cursor position, in characters. The coordinates are the column and row of a screen buffer character cell. The coordinates must be within the boundaries of the console screen buffer.

Clear screen/cls is not meant for animations.